# do something after user click the notification center message in MobileFirst app?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Page navigating and communicating with backend system should be done after users click the notification center message entering the app.

But where should my code be ?

Answer (score 0):

In the same function that handles the incoming notification.

If you're using Event Source-based notifications then that would be the `pushNotificationReceived()` function. Replace the alerts with required applicative logic.

```
function pushNotificationReceived(props, payload) {
    alert("pushNotificationReceived invoked");
    alert("props :: " + JSON.stringify(props));
    alert("payload :: " + JSON.stringify(payload));
}
```

If you're using broadcast/tag notifications it is done in a similar fashion. From the sample application you can do something like the following, just replace with your required applicative logic:

```
WL.Client.Push.onMessage = function (props, payload) {
    WL.SimpleDialog.show("Tag Notifications", "Provider notification data: " + JSON.stringify(props), [ {
        text : 'Close',
        handler : function() {
            WL.SimpleDialog.show("Tag Notifications", "Application notification data: " + JSON.stringify(payload), [ {
                text : 'Close',
                handler : function() {}
              }]);      
        }
    }]);
};
```

Comment: Could this be placed in `initOptions.js` ?

Comment: This is app logic and it should sit in main.js... you can place it anywhere you want, but I suspect your code will become a jungle...